# JSON output Google Maps Geocode API returns question marks in address, in browser correct output

Tags: powershell

I have created a script:

```
$API    = "<That is secret>"
$LatLng = "47.5560960732389,7.5917686522"
$URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$LatLng&key=$API"
$URL
$Result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -ContentType "application/json; charset=UTF-8" -Method Get -UseBasicParsing | ConvertFrom-Json 

if($Result.status -eq "OK")
 {
  $Result.results.formatted_address
  Write-Host "------------------------------------"
  $Result.results.formatted_address[0]
  [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(28591).GetBytes($Result.results.formatted_address[0]))
 }
```

And the output looks like:

```
M??nsterpl. 12, 4051 Basel, Switzerland
M??nsterpl. 14, 4051 Basel, Switzerland
M??nsterpl. 14, 4051 Basel, Switzerland
M??nsterberg 13, 4051 Basel, Switzerland
HH4R+CP Basel, Switzerland
M??nsterpl. 9, 4051 Basel, Switzerland
Altstadt Grossbasel, Basel, Switzerland
4051 Basel, Switzerland
Basel, Switzerland
Basel-Stadt, Switzerland
Basel City, Switzerland
Switzerland
------------------------------------
M??nsterpl. 12, 4051 Basel, Switzerland
M??nsterpl. 12, 4051 Basel, Switzerland
```

If I enter the created URL (stored in the variable $URL) copy-and-paste in Firefox the address is shown in the correct layout:

[image]

What can I do to resolve this issue?
Thanks... TheStingPilot

Answer (score 0):

```
$Result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -Method Get -UseBasicParsing
$Result = ($Result.Content | ConvertFrom-JSON)
```

Only this works...